# Convert any file (Readable as Text File) to Excel Format (.xlsx) virtually then convert as dataframe -Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I almost completely done with my project - an app to transpose a machine log with thousand of rows into columns and analyze several data from it thru pandas.

But I have to manually open the machine log file first and save as .xlsx then open the save .xlsx file in the app in order to convert it to dataframe.

Is there any way to open the file in python virtually and convert to data frame?

or Open the file > then convert to excel > then convert to data frame?

I've tried:

```
def openanyfile():
    f = open("Machine.LOG", "r")
    print(f.read())
    data = pd.DataFrame(f)
    print(data)
```

It was successfully read and print the file but when converting to pd.DataFrame it results to "Empty DataFrame".

Attached here is the sample raw file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M6BXpqn10MJCc5mUfg9dGCJKAz_05G3W/view?usp=sharing

It is readable as text file.

When opened to MS Excel, it will create 2 columns which I manipulated and converted as dataframe thru pd.read_excel.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is your data in xml form. Pandas introduced a method [```read_xml```](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) but it comes with the version 1.3.0 which isn't in pip available yet. You can take a look at this [post](https://medium.com/@robertopreste/from-xml-to-pandas-dataframes-9292980b1c1c) which shows how to parse xml to pandas

Comment: @99_m4n Thank you for this. I'll try..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution. One proposal: You could use the `xml.etree.ElementTree` from the Python standard library. With the file you've provided this seems to work:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree

with open('Machine.LOG', 'rt') as file:
    data = '<Root>' + file.read() + '</Root>'
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
        {item.tag: item.text for item in record}
        for record in ETree.fromstring(data)
     ])
```

The file contains no all enclosing tag, so I had to add some artificial tag `<Root>` which has no real meaning.

Result (`print(df)`:

```
                     Timestamp  ... Value
0     FRI NOV 02 04:36:42 2018  ...   NaN
1     FRI NOV 02 04:36:42 2018  ...   NaN
2     FRI NOV 02 04:36:46 2018  ...   NaN
3     FRI NOV 02 04:37:53 2018  ...   NaN
4     FRI NOV 02 04:37:56 2018  ...   NaN
...                        ...  ...   ...
9069  TUE NOV 06 03:09:09 2018  ...   NaN
9070  TUE NOV 06 03:09:13 2018  ...   NaN
9071  TUE NOV 06 03:09:14 2018  ...   NaN
9072  TUE NOV 06 03:09:15 2018  ...   NaN
9073  TUE NOV 06 03:09:16 2018  ...   NaN
```

Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for this..
Already tried, and it works fine.